# Git setup remote tracking branch

Tags: git

I want to track a remote master branch from a new remote repository. Both do already exist.

How do I go about this in git? I can't seem to get it right. I tried:

```
git remote add otherRepo git://...
git branch -t myTrack otherRepo/master
```

However, I get the following error:

`fatal: Not a valid object name: 'otherRepo/master'`.

Comment: Did you do `git fetch otherRepo` before trying to branch? `git remote add` just configures the remote, it does not automatically do a fetch. If you already fetched it, are you sure it has a branch named master? `git branch -r` or `git remote show -n otherRepo`  (*after fetching it*) to check which branches it has.

Comment: @crhis: thanks, now it works. It seems logical I need to fetch, however this adds, all the other branches from otherRepo too. Can I just fetch otherRepo/Master? I don't want to clutter up branch -r.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As covered in the comments: `git remote add otherRepo …` only configures the remote, it does not fetch anything from it. You will need to run `git fetch otherRepo` to fetch the branches of the remote repository before you can create local branches based on them.

---

(responding to further comment by OP)

If you only want to keep track of a single branch from the remote repository, you can reconfigure your remote's fetch property (`remote.otherRepo.fetch`).

```
# done as a shell function to avoid repeating the repository and branch names
configure-single-branch-fetch() {
    git config remote."$1".fetch +refs/heads/"$2":refs/remotes/"${1}/${2}"
}
configure-single-branch-fetch "$remoteName" "$branch"
# i.e. # configure-single-branch-fetch otherRepo master
```

After this, `git fetch otherRepo` will only fetch the remote repository's `master` branch into the `otherRepo/master` ‘remote tracking branch’ in your local repository.

To cleanup the other ‘remote tracking branches’, you could delete them all and re-fetch just the one you want, or you could selectively delete all of them except just the one you want:

```
git for-each-ref --shell --format='git branch -dr %(refname:short)' refs/remotes/otherRepo | sh -nv
# remove the -nv if the commands look OK, then
git fetch otherRepo

# OR

git for-each-ref --shell --format='test %(refname:short) != otherRepo/master && git branch -dr %(refname:short)' refs/remotes/otherRepo | sh -nv
# remove the -nv if the commands look OK
```

If you decide that you want to track more than one remote branch, but not all of them, you can have multiple fetch configurations (with `git config --add remote."$remoteName".fetch …` or by using `git config --edit` to directly duplicate and edit the line in your repository's config file).

If you also want to avoid fetching tags from the remote, configure your remote's tagopt property (`remote.otherRepo.tagopt`).

```
git config remote."$remoteName".tagopt --no-tags
# i.e. # git config remote.otherRepo.tagopt --no-tags
```

Comment: thanks for this very complete answer. Seems awful such an easy operation is made so complex. Whatever

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
git checkout -b myTrack otherRepo/master
```

This will create a new branch myTrack, which tracks the otherRepo/master branch.

Comment: Does not work, the error given is:

fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'otherRepo/master' which can not be resolved as commit?
`

Comment: Worked for me after doing the remote add and the fetch.